# Custom Loss Function in Keras - Iterate through TensorFlow

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, lstm, loss-function

I am working on creating a custom loss function in Keras.
Here is an example.

```
import keras.backend as K
def test(y_true, y_pred):
     loss = K.square(y_pred - y_true)
     loss = K.mean(loss, axis = 1)
return loss
```

Now in this example, I would like to only subtract let's say specific values
from y_pred, but since this is in tensorflow, how do I iterate throw them.

For example, can I iterate through y_pred to pick values? and how?
Lets say for this example, the batch size is 5.

I have tried things such as
y_pred[0...i]
tf.arange and many more...

Answer (score 0):

Just pass it when you are compiling model. Like

```
model.compile(optimizer='sgd', loss = test)
```

Keras will Iterate over it automatically.
You have also intentaion error in return statement.

```
import keras.backend as K
def test(y_true, y_pred):
     loss = K.square(y_pred - y_true)
     loss = K.mean(loss, axis = 1)
     return loss 

def test_accuracy(y_true, y_pred):
     return 1 - test(y_true, y_pred)
```

By this way you can pass your custom loss function to the model and you can also pass accuracy funtion similarly

```
model.compile(optimizer='sgd', loss = test, metrics=[test_accuracy])
```

Comment: hello Sohaib, i am creating a custom loss function so I can find the average of the highest values in a set interval from the y_pred. So I understand that it would automatically iterate, but is it possible to make it iterate every set intervals of my choosing?

Comment: Yaa! you can I will try to answer this in some time after checking it on my notebook.

Comment: Thank you! and also it would be helpful if you can show how I can pick a value from the y_pred. So simply put in an example, I want to be able to check the highest value, lets say every 10 points, and then find the loss of that